# extjs4 MVC Ext.ComponentQuery.query(...).setVisible is not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs4

I have button in a view as below:

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.layout = {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center',
        pack: 'center'
    };

    this.items = [
        Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            name:'loginButton',
            action:'login',
            text: 'Login',
            scale   : 'medium',
            width: 100,
            itemId:'loginButton',
            handler: function() {
                //any default action here
            }

        })
    ];
```

now in a controller I want to hide that button, I wrote

```
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[text=Login]').setVisible(false);
```

But it getting an error.

```
TypeError: Ext.ComponentQuery.query(...).setVisible is not a function
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

`query` returns an array, so you need to access the first index.

Comment: how? please give me example code. I had tried with 
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[text=Login]')[0].setVisible(false);

but didn't worked.
btw, thanks for quick response..

Comment: Use the console of your browser and see what you are getting back... **Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[text=Login]')[0].setVisible(false);** is working perfectly! Maybe you have two buttons with text 'Login' and you are hidding the other one.